# Adding paths to config file in most efficent way via Ansible

Tags: regex, variables, ansible, supervisord

I wrote a task that is responsible for changing supervisor config file. The case is that on some servers we have more than one app running workers, so sometimes more than one path needs to be added to `include` section of `supervisor.conf`.

Currently I wrote this task in `/roles/supervisor/tasks/main.yml/`:

```
- name: Add apps paths in include section
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
    regex: '^files ='
    line: 'files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf /home/app/{{ app_name }}/releases/app/shared/supervisor/*.conf /home/dev/{{ app_name2 }}/releases/dev/shared/supervisor/*.conf'
  when: ansible_hostname = 'ser-db-10'
  notify: restart supervisor
  tags: multi_workers
```

... and added in `/roles/supervisor/defaults/main.yml/` this:

```
app_name: bla
app_name2: blabla
```

It works, but I don't like the thing that there are two application paths hardcoded in `line` and maybe I should also add variable in place of `ser-db-10`.

I am wondering how to rebuild this task to make it more independent.

What I mean is, if there are 4 apps, add 4 paths, if there are 2 apps, add 2 paths.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how to put together the parameter *line*, the play below

```
- hosts: test_01
  vars:
    app_name1: A
    app_name2: B
    my_conf:
      test_01:
        lines:
          - '/etc/*.conf'
          - '/etc/{{ app_name1 }}/*.conf'
          - '/etc/{{ app_name2 }}/*.conf'

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "files = {{ my_conf[inventory_hostname].lines|join(' ') }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "files = /etc/*.conf /etc/A/*.conf /etc/B/*.conf"
```

With appropriate dictionary *my_conf* the task below should do the job

```
- name: Add apps paths in include section
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
    regex: '^files ='
    line: "files = {{ my_conf[inventory_hostname].lines|join(' ') }}"
  notify: restart supervisor
  tags: multi_workers
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank you! I will test it and let you know whether it works or not.

Comment: It works as it should, when executed as playbook.yml but I unsuccessfully trying to convert this solution to role. I was trying to add `- name: Check existing apps on server` before `hosts: test_01` part, but I get error `The offending line appears to be: - vars:` so I suppose it can't be done like that. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: I have no idea what do you want to accomplish. The best option would be to open a new question. [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Avoid irrelevant complexity like `/home/app/{{ app_name }}/releases/app/shared/supervisor/*.conf` when shorter version e.g. `/etc/{{ app_name }}/*.conf` does the job as well.